# Flex column, column exceeding container width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't get the flex: column working so that child elements don't exeed the parent. The left block is an image, it has to be 100% of containers height:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid blue 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tall {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}

.row {
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: red;
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tall"></div>
  <div class="row">This is a text that should be multiline, with automatic width depending on the left block width.</div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

The right rows no matter what I try are always exceeding the container, their width is always container width, not the remaining space widht. How can I achieve it?

Comment: I don't know why someone gave -1 to this question. The question a real problem, the suggested answer is a workaround, the correct answer is "it cannot be done with given structure and css".

Answer (score 2):

I would change the direction of your flex so it is row and remove the flex wrap, then I would wrap your rows in a div with `flex-grow:1` and remove the height from tall:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid blue 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.tall {
  width: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}

.row-holder {
  flex-grow:1;
}
.row {
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: red;
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tall"></div>
  <div class="row-holder">
    <div class="row">This is a text that should be multiline, with automatic width depending on the left block width.</div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, yes this gives exactly the expected result. But do you know the solution (and reason) for the issue with column layout?

Comment: Guess it's because you didn't give the row a width - I guess if you have a fixed width container, you can just give your row a width of 200px and your original solution will work.  I think the issue is because you use flex-wrap with column and not giving the children a width, it will end up like yours

Comment: Ok, but this is the thing, the row should be automatically stretching/schrinking, without a fixed width :/

Comment: which is why you need to change the direction of your flex - don't try fudge a solution on styles that won't work, learn how the styles work and use them to your advantage